# Android: voice_command app only launches successfully once per bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

thank you for your time.

I have written a small app that is triggered through a bluetooth button push.  It greets the user with text-to-speech, and then prompts them for a command that is processed with voice-to-text.

It all works well except for the fact that my app will only launch once per bluetooth connection.  The next time I push and hold my bluetooth button, all I hear is a *beep* but no app launches.  If I disconnect bluetooth and reconnect bluetooth, my app will successfully launch, but again, only the first time.  I have tried another app as my default bluetooth app and it works fine each time it is called, so this must be an issue with my design.

In order to make my app eligible as the default for a bluetooth button push, I included the voice_command action in my Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

All of my work is housed in one activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, OnInitListener, OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
```

Using text-to-speech, I know that the the first time the app is launched, it makes it to my first text-to-speech call which I have written in the onInit function:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    }
```

When my app is done and calls finish(), text-to-speech tells me that the app goes through the following sequence:

```
onPause();
onStop();
onDestroy();
```

When I push the bluetooth button for the second time on the existing bluetooth connection, my application does not make it to onInit().  I can be fairly sure of that since the text-to-speech is not read aloud.  This suggests to me that the app is not launched at all.

After the first successful app launch per bluetooth connection, I have tried clearing the app's cache and also forcing the app closed through the settings menu.  Nothing helps.

Any suggestions as to where I can look to continue debugging would be much appreciated.  I am testing on a Nexus 4.

Thank you,

Greg

Comment: I am also a newbee in andorid app, but don't you need a service running in background and listening to all the intents broadcasted and be handled those in an activity ?

Comment: Hi bt_user.  I thought that in this case, since my app is simply being assigned as a default app for a bluetooth button push, that all the bluetooth complexity is being handled by the operating system.  Shouldn't a bluetooth button push launch the same app each time it is pushed?  In my case, it launches successfully, but only the first time.

Comment: You can check in adb logcat for the intent broadcasted when bluetooth button is pressed for the second time, i believe that your activity is destroyed as your activity has already gone through the process of onPause();onStop() and onDestroy(). Check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Logcat does not display the intent broadcasted from the bluetooth button push since it is not part of my app.  I am essentially doing no bluetooth programming.  The bluetooth button push sends out the intent of android.intent.action.voice_command which launches my app since my app is set to be the default app for this intent.  My app launches on the first bluetooth button push, from a destroyed state.  Is a different call made the second time you push a bluetooth button?  Is it no longer an intent of .voice_command?  Is finish() the wrong way to end the app?

Comment: I understand now bt_user, thank you for your help.  BluetoothHeadset class is what I needed, including listeners etc.

Comment: Remove this two lines:  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />